# How can I punch a hole in a Plane in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js

I would like to use `Plane` and `PlaneHelper` to create some default pavement for streets around houses.

The reason for the `Plane` is, that it is, to my understanding, the "only" infinite thing.

But how can I punch holes in there for e.g. buildings?

As buildings can have cellars, just putting them on top will not work.

Comment: Normally you'd build a city in a modeling program like [blender](https://blender.org). Doing it by trying to create holes in a plane will not be trival. There's a method called Constructive Solid Geometry [CSG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry) and there are libraries but it's generally to slow to use at runtime as well as often buggy because of edge cases.

Comment: You are confusing `Plane` and `PlaneHelper` with `PlaneBufferGeometry`. `Plane` is a mathematical construct used for clipping planes. You can use an `alphaMap` with your planar `Mesh` to punch holes in it.